# mod_rewrite domain to directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want rewrite `example.com` url to `example.com/ru`

For example if url is `example.com/books` I want have `example.com/ru/books`

I think I can't this do with `header()` function

This method is also incorrect

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://www.example.com/ru">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit .htaccess to redirect user queries at / level to the new /ru/ level.
This should work for your purpose:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ru/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ru/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.htaccess` file for mod rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: True, but depending on the scope of the project this can be overcome by creating another .htaccess file in /ru to turn RewriteEngine Off. OP wasn't very specific in the URL needs for the project.

Answer (score 0):

From the apache mod_rewrite documentation at 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html:

```
RewriteCond %{Kramnik} !^/ru/$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) www.example.nl:/%{Kramnik}/$1 [L,R]
```

However, the rewrite engine should be enabled first. In Ubuntu you will enable it a2enmod rewrite.

If you have a virtual host file, then take a look if AllowOverride is set to All. As long as it is set to None, `.htaccess` file will be ignored.